# SwiftUI: How to properly allow user to change dragged element's colour afer drag gesture

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create app that allows user to drag through the grid, and change colour of each touched cell. Some kind of pixel art drawing machine, but after making simple example it doesn't work, and I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
struct Cell: View, Hashable, Equatable {
    @State var color: Color = .red
    let id = UUID()
    
    static func == (lhs: Cell, rhs: Cell) -> Bool {
        return lhs.color == rhs.color
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(color)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .foregroundColor(color)
    }
}

struct Grid: View {
    
    @State private var cells: [[Cell]] = (0..<10).map { _ in
        (0..<10).map { _ in Cell() }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(cells, id: \.self) { row in
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(row, id: \.id) { cell in
                        cell
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .background(Color.black)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    let width = 40
                    let height = 40
                    let x = Int(value.location.x / CGFloat(width))
                    let y = Int(value.location.y / CGFloat(height))
                    // Make sure the indices are within the bounds of the grid
                    if x >= 0 && x < 10 && y >= 0 && y < 10 {
                        self.cells[y][x].color = .green
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good to create separate models for cells.
here is a quick fix.

```
struct CellView: View {
    var cell: Cell
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .foregroundColor(cell.color)
    }
}

struct Cell: Identifiable {
    var color: Color = .red
    let id = UUID()
}

struct Grid: View {
    
    @State private var cells: [[Cell]] = (0..<10).map { _ in
        (0..<10).map { _ in Cell() }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(cells.indices, id: \.self) { row in
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(cells[row], id: \.id) { cell in
                        CellView(cell: cell)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .background(Color.black)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    let width = 40
                    let height = 40
                    let x = Int(value.location.x / CGFloat(width))
                    let y = Int(value.location.y / CGFloat(height))
                    // Make sure the indices are within the bounds of the grid
                    if x >= 0 && x < 10 && y >= 0 && y < 10 {
                        self.cells[y][x].color = .green
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I my God I am so thankful for that!!

Answer (score 0):

@raja-kishan approach is good but you can just remove `@State` from `@State var color: Color = .red` from your Cell Struct like this.

```swift
struct Cell: View, Hashable, Equatable {
    var color: Color = .red
    let id = UUID()
    
    static func == (lhs: Cell, rhs: Cell) -> Bool {
        return lhs.color == rhs.color
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(color)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .foregroundColor(color)
    }
}
```